# Can somebody suggest me whether ProZilla available for Windows (Cygwin or in other format) or not?

Tags: cygwin

Is ProZilla available for Windows? If yes, please share details. Any kind of help is appreciated. I know its there in Linux but I want to use it under Windows. If it is available for Cygwin, well and good.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

Not on cygwin.

https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Neither as cygport package

ftp://sourceware.org/pub/cygwinports/portslist.txt